# Can't seem to get submit/buttons/anchors to line up

Tags: css

Some times I may may want an anchor beside a submit button, but I always seem to have problems lining them up ...

```
a, input[type=submit], input[type=button], button {
  font-family: arial;
  background: #fff;
  color: #777;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px !important;  
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cXgzM/

with that, anchors are still 2 pixels short

Comment: Couldn't you use an extra CSS declaration for the anchor to resolve this issue? Might get pretty tricky this way…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
a
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I updated your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cXgzM/1/). Note that this property doesn't work in IE7 and lower. :)

Comment: erm on Firefox 3.6.13 on my computer, the `<a>` looks too tall now, http://imgur.com/wbRfU.jpg ... wonder how jQuery UI does it ...

Comment: That's quite odd! to fi this in Firefox (you'll have to send Firefox its own CSS) use `line-height: 17px !important;` on the `<a>`. Unless someone else can come up with a better solution?